# Split a header-only library into implementation and header

Tags: c++, header-files

Pardon my strong wording, but I believe that header files are just as bad as `using namespace std;`. I want to use a library called CLI11, which is header-only. Is there a way to convert that header-only file into two files, the header file (declarations only), and a `.cpp` file containing the implementation?

Ideally, something automated, not cut and paste.

Comment: There seems to be a proposal about that: https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11/issues/626

Answer (score 0):

[Visual assist](https://www.wholetomato.com/) has a 'Move implementation to source file' routine. I don't think it will handle an entire complex header file or a set of header files.

Perhaps more practically, you can mitigate header file pollution by managing your include directories carefully. CLI parsing, for instance, should only be needed by a single cpp file, so you could set that cpp file up to compile with a special include directory and then only use the library in that cpp file.

Comment: I use VSCode, if that is relevant. I also don't want to use Visual Assist, since that's non-free and I don't have the money.

Comment: If you really want to 'clean up' the code you could implement something with https://clang.llvm.org/docs/RefactoringEngine.html - I think the only people that use these things have huge codebases, though. Not easy to use. I don't know of anything that's as easy to use as VA but as powerful as the clang RE

Comment: I haven't written any code yet, I don't exactly have a huge codebase yet, but I'll look into the clang RE, or use a different command line parser.